# Access 2016 - Linked Excel Tbl made into Qry - get Data type Mismatch when trying Unmatched

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

This seems like a very simple question, however, I am still not getting rid of the Data Type Mismatch. Scenario:

-> Excel File link in as table [tbl_Mast_CC_List], I convert the possible Cost Center Numbers into Values for safety via query, there are NO text variables in the Cost Center or preceding 000's, next arrow

-> qry_CC_Clean is `CostCenter:Val([tbl_Mast_CC_List.CostCenter])`

-> then I create the Unmatched Query, here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    qry_CC_S1_Clean_F2F_Alloc.DataName
    , qry_CC_S1_Clean_F2F_Alloc.Year
    , qry_CC_S1_Clean_F2F_Alloc.CostCenter
FROM qry_CC_S1_Clean_F2F_Alloc 
LEFT JOIN qry_CC_S1_Clean_Mast_CC_List 
    ON qry_CC_S1_Clean_F2F_Alloc.CostCenter = qry_CC_S1_Clean_Mast_CC_List.CostCenter
WHERE (((qry_CC_S1_Clean_Mast_CC_List.CostCenter) Is Null))
ORDER BY qry_CC_S1_Clean_F2F_Alloc.CostCenter;
```

The only time I can get it to work is if I make table of the query and I don't really want to do that. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated because I have to run this unmatched query against numerous tables to make sure the company is not missing any cost centers rolling through.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to using the `val()` function and trying to test it against nulls.  My understanding is that `val()` doesn't return nulls, it returns 0 when it can't find anything.  You might be better off running the conversion in the opposite direction, i.e. using `CStr()` on the numeric CostCenter field and comparing that to the text data from Excel.

Alternately you could change the Excel field itself to a number format instead of text.